# Wait for all resources to be loaded

Tags: angular.js, coffeescript

In my application I need some resources to be loaded and I have services to load each of them and then I need some point to know that all requests finished. First thought was to use $q.all with array of promises from that services. But it would be resolved only if all promises resolved which is now always the right case because some of them may be rejected. Finally I ended up with this code:

```
.service 'dataRepository', ($q, Categories, Items, Settings, Session) ->
    data: {}
    fetch: ->
        res = $q.defer()
        foo = 
            categories: Categories.fetch()
            items: Items.fetch()
            settings: Settings.fetch()
            user: Session.fetch()

        cEnded = 0
        for k, p of foo
            p.then do (k) =>
                (result) => 
                    @data[k] = result 

            p.finally do (k) =>
                =>
                    cEnded++
                    if cEnded is _.size foo
                        res.resolve @data
        res.promise
```

I can put result of `dataRepository.fetch()` in resolve of `$urlRouterProvider` of ui-router and in my controllers I can be sure that data loading finished.

But this is not looking like a good solution. So the question is, are there better ways to wait for the requests pool?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I'm surprised there isn't a `$q.some` or so to do exactly that.

I think this is a good solution for the problem, though putting it in a separate function would be nice.  (Can't think of any reasons to not do it like this either.)

Comment: you mean to extend $q?

Comment: That's a possibility of course.

Comment: Here you can find some ideas to extend `$q`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888104/angularjs-q-wait-for-all-even-when-1-rejected